# How do I run simple Go servers on 2 ports on an EC2 instance?

Tags: go, amazon-ec2

**EDIT:** I didn't make clear that this works fine on port 80 but not port 8080.

I have a simple server to test OAuth2 written in Golang. It defaults to port 80. I compile it, then run like this:

```
$ sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' ./c3
$ nohup ./c3
```

Works like a charm.

My goal is to show how it works differently depending on configuration, and I'd like the vendor's support team to be able to log onto either version, simply depending on whether they append :8080 to the site's URL.

I have a -port option, so I open another terminal, log into EC2, and run this:

```
$ sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' ./c3
$ nohup ./c3 -port=8080
```

This doesn't connect to mysite.com:8080 and I can't figure out why. The program just hangs.

My security group rules allow all outbound traffic. Inbound is restricted to 80, 8080, 22, and 443.

Comment: Did you open port 8080 in your security group?

Comment: Which address does your server bind to?

Comment: ofirule, I may not understand your question. I allow outbound traffic to all ports. Inbound traffic is allowed on ports 80 and 8080.

Comment: bserdar, I don't know how to answer that... It's a domain name, bound to an Amazon elastic IP, but I'm a novice at admin stuff so I may have misunderstood the question.